# Log out user / Invalidate token when someone restarts the application windows service

Tags: authentication, jwt, windows-services, token, access-token

I have an application that is an windows service.
When someone restarts the windows service, I want the user to be required to log in again (So log him out at restart or invalidate his jwt token).
The application is on premise so only one user is logged in.

I tried with "ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero" and "ValidateLifeTime = true" but after I restart the service, the user is still logged in.

I have something like this for Authentication
[image]

And I'm using TopShelf for windows services.

[image]

Do you have any ideas about how I can do this?